# iOS Swift - Play youtube video with full screen video player

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am developing an iOS 8 project on Swift. Is it possible to play a youtube video inside the system's full screen video player?

Answer (score 2):

Youtube video plays within a UIWebview (and not used http streaming right within your app) but it can go full screen. Youtube provides a [helper library](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) in order to play yt vide within your app.

Comment: I tried using the helper library, but it always plays in line and doesn't go full screen. Is there a way to make it open fullscreen?

Comment: Best Choice to play Youtube Videos without Ads is

https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit